# Select Negative values only if exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i am new to sql server. i am having some problem when selecting values for report. i am having the following columns:

```
name, snap, current, percent.
```

i want to select only negative values if exists in the column "percent" if not select +ve values only.

for example:

if i am having -1, -10, 0, 10 then it should select only -1, -10.

i tried the following query, but its giving both +ve and -ve values.

```
selectname, snap, current, percent 
where percent = 
CASE WHEN percent < 0 then percent 
when percent > 0 then percent
```

i don't know how to use if else in where condition. Can anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If negative values exist _at all_ in the table, or _for that name/snap/current_?

Comment: please don't use shorthand like "+ve" it makes it brutal to read.

Comment: for the column percent @Joachim

Comment: Nice. Thanks to everyone. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IF EXISTS` to check the condition and then get the desired result

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE percent < 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT [name], [snap], [current], [percent] FROM TABLENAME WHERE [percent] < 0
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT [name], [snap], [current], [percent] FROM TABLENAME WHERE [percent] > 0
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `UNION ALL` to separate two conditions. Due to them being opposite, only one part of query will return rows.

```
SELECT [name], [snap], [current], [percent]
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [percent] < 0) 
AND [percent] < 0

UNION ALL

SELECT [name], [snap], [current], [percent] 
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [percent] < 0)
AND [percent] > 0
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01973/2)**

**[Demo with non-negative values](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e85fe/1)**